# How to fix incorrect bandwidth in statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.kdensity or seaborn.kdeplot?

Tags: python, seaborn, statsmodels, python-3.7

I'm translating some of my R files into Python and I have some problems with setting the bandwidth in my KDE plots with an Epanechnikov Kernel in Python.

I have tried to use the function seaborn.kdeplot(), as well as statsmodels.nonparametric.kde.kdensity(), but never got the correct result.

Until now, I didn't find a pattern how the bandwidth in Python is scaled or standardized.
Moreover, if I use the gaussian kernel, the plots from R and Python are the same. So maybe the Epanechnikov Kernel is calculated differently?

I used the following codes for creating the KDE plot in Python:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.kdeplot(y,kernel = 'epa', bw = 0.1)
```

and

```
from statsmodels.nonparametric.kde import kdensity
density = kdensity(y, kernel='epa', bw=0.1)
plt.plot(density[1],density[0], color = 'red')
```

The output in both isn't very smooth: https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/48911472/55010186-1382fc80-4fe4-11e9-999f-263ea9bf62c9.png

However, it should look like the output in R (or in STATA as they are the same) which is more smooth:

```
plot(density(y,bw=0.1, kernel ="epanechnikov"), col="red")
```

https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/48911472/55010088-e3d3f480-4fe3-11e9-8d84-ebd54c5b8bc9.png

Comment: Could this be related to https://stackoverflow.com/a/55367955/230468?

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the grid size over sns.kdplot, the default value is 100,  while I believe in density from R is around 512. Hope it helps

Comment: In the meantime, I found out that because of different standardization of the  Epanechnikov Kernel I had to multiply the bandwidth by sqrt(5). However, then the seaborn.kdeplot() function showed a different plot than when I used the code directly with statsmodels. After adjusting the grid size as you suggested, I finally got the same plots from both codes. Thank you.