# Why do stat_density (R; ggplot2) and gaussian_kde (Python; scipy) differ?

Tags: python, r, ggplot2, scipy, kernel-density

I am attempting to produce a KDE based PDF estimate on a series of distributions that may not be normally distributed.

I like the way ggplot's stat_density in R seems to recognize every incremental bump in frequency, but cannot replicate this via Python's scipy-stats-gaussian_kde method, which seems to oversmooth.

I have set up my R code as follows:

```
ggplot(test, aes(x=Val, color = as.factor(Class), group=as.factor(Class))) +
             stat_density(geom='line',kernel='gaussian',bw='nrd0' 
                                                            #nrd0='Silverman'
                                                            ,size=1,position='identity')
```

[image: R example]

And my python code is:

```
kde = stats.gaussian_kde(data.ravel())
kde.set_bandwidth(bw_method='silverman')
```

[image: python example]

Stats docs show [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.3/topics/bandwidth) that nrd0 is the silverman method for bw adjust.

Based on the code above, I am using the same kernals (gaussian) and bandwidth methods (Silverman).

Can anyone explain why the results are so different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There seems to be disagreement about what Silverman's Rule is. TL;DR - scipy uses a worse version of the rule that only works well on unimodal data that is normally distributed. R uses a better version that is "the best of both worlds" and works "for a wide range of densities".

The [scipy docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html) say that Silverman's rule is [implemented as](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.2.1/scipy/stats/kde.py#L469-L470):

```
def silverman_factor(self):
    return power(self.neff*(self.d+2.0)/4.0, -1./(self.d+4))
```

Where `d` is the number of dimensions (1, in your case) and `neff` is the effective sample size (number of points, assuming no weights). So the scipy bandwidth is `(n * 3 / 4) ^ (-1 / 5)` (times the standard deviation, computed in a different method).

By contrast, R's [`stats` package docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/stats/versions/3.5.3/topics/bandwidth) describe Silverman's method as "0.9 times the minimum of the standard deviation and the interquartile range divided by 1.34 times the sample size to the negative one-fifth power", which can also be verified in R code, typing `bw.nrd0` in the console gives:

```
function (x) 
{
    if (length(x) < 2L) 
        stop("need at least 2 data points")
    hi <- sd(x)
    if (!(lo <- min(hi, IQR(x)/1.34))) 
        (lo <- hi) || (lo <- abs(x[1L])) || (lo <- 1)
    0.9 * lo * length(x)^(-0.2)
}
```

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_density_estimation#A_rule-of-thumb_bandwidth_estimator), on the other hand, gives "Silverman's Rule of Thumb" as one of many possible names for the estimator:

```
1.06 * sigma * n ^ (-1 / 5)
```

The wikipedia version is equivalent to the scipy version.

All three sources (scipy docs, Wikipedia, and R docs) cite the same original reference: Silverman, B.W. (1986). *Density Estimation for Statistics and Data Analysis*. London: Chapman & Hall/CRC. p. 48. ISBN 978-0-412-24620-3. Wikipedia and R specifically cite page 48, whereas scipy's docs do not mention a page number. (I have submitted an edit to Wikipedia to update its page reference to p.45, see below.)

Reading the Silverman paper, on page 45, equation 3.28 is what is used in the Wikipedia article: `(4 / 3) ^ (1 / 5) * sigma * n ^ (-1 / 5) ~= 1.06 * sigma * n ^ (-1 / 5)`. Scipy uses the same method, rewriting `(4 / 3) ^ (1 / 5)` as the equivalent `(3 / 4) ^ (-1 / 5)`. Silverman describes this method:

> While (3.28) will work well if the population really is normally distributed, it may oversmooth somewhat if the population is multimodal... as the mixture becomes more strongly bimodal the formula (3.28) will oversmooth more and more, relative to the optimal choice of smoothing parameter.

The scipy docs [reference this weakness](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.gaussian_kde.html), stating:

> It includes automatic bandwidth determination. The estimation works best for a unimodal distribution; bimodal or multi-modal distributions tend to be oversmoothed.

However, the Silverman article continues, improving on the method scipy uses to get to the method used by R and Stata. On page 48, we get the equation 3.31:

```
h = 0.9 * A * n ^ (-1 / 5)
# A defined on previous page, eqn 3.30
A = min(standard deviation, interquartile range / 1.34)
```

Silverman describes this method as:

> The best of both possible worlds... In summary, the choice ([eqn] 3.31) for the smoothing parameter will do very well for a wide range of densities and is trivial to evaluate. For many purposes it will certainly be an adequate choice of window width, and for others it will be a good starting point for subsequent fine-tuning.

So, it seems Wikipedia and Scipy use a simple version of  an estimator proposed by Silverman with known weaknesses. R and Stata use a better version.

Comment: Wow! Thank you for the prompt and detailed reply. I certainly prefer eq 3.31 to 3.28, especially considering the chance for multi-modality in the data. Interesting that there is such a dichotomy in their uses.

Comment: Yeah, the paper was an interested skim, made me really appreciate how much work has gone into these defaults.

Comment: Any thoughts on how to utilize this with gaussian_kde() in python? I have successfully replicated the correct nrd0 h value in python, but when applied via bw_method, it produces unexpected results. The eq. 3.31 figure (that nrd0 produces) seems to be around 0.05, while entering something closer to 0.5 in bw_method seems to replicate the results in gaussian_kde. The nrd0 (eq. 3.31) value of h produces a jagged curve with far too little smoothing.

Comment: Sorry, I'm just a Python hobbyist. I'd suggest opening a new question on that (and referencing this one for context).

Comment: So... not sure if this is correct or not, but setting the bandwidth method in gaussian_kde to the 3.31 h value divided by the std seems to do the trick. I guess they multiply it by std after the method is set. Weird.